# SASS ignores variables, defined in if-statement

Tags: variables, if-statement, sass

I have one file named style.scss with the following code:

```scss
@import 'variables';
    
body {
    color: $text-color;
    background: $background-color;
}
```

And one partial named _variables.scss:

```scss
$colorscheme: white;
    
@if $colorscheme == white {
    $text-color: #333;
    $background-color: #fff;
}
@else {
    $text-color: #ccc;
    $background-color: #333;
}
```

The if-statement works properly, but the variables defined inside, do not work.
When I try to compile it, I keep getting:

> Syntax error: Undefined variable: “$text-color”.

Comment: I stepped into the same thing actually. I was wondering that my sass code didn't work after a few months. Noticed, that I updated my grunt-sass (node-sass/libsass) version. I'm 100% sure that defining variables inside `@if/@else` worked at that time. I played around a lot with that. Maybe it was a bug and it shouldn't have worked. :D Thanks for clarifying this anyway, @cimmanon.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That's completely expected.  Variables have a *scope* to them.  If you define them inside of a control block (like an `if` statement), then they won't be available outside.  So, what you need to do is initialize it outside like so:

```scss
$text-color: null;
$background-color: null;
@if $colorscheme == white {
    $text-color: #333;
    $background-color: #fff;
}
@else {
    $text-color: #ccc;
    $background-color: #333;
}
```

Or...

```scss
$text-color: #ccc;
$background-color: #333;
@if $colorscheme == white {
    $text-color: #333;
    $background-color: #fff;
}
```

Though it would be less verbose to use the `if()` function like this:

```scss
$text-color: if($colorscheme == white, #333, #ccc);
$background-color: if($colorscheme == white, #fff, #333);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.
So it is behaves pretty much like variables in PHP-functions.
I don’t like to create empty variables, but that does the trick.

Is there any command, equal to the _global_ command from PHP? It would feel a little bit more comfortable for me.

I tried your last example and it worked, but I have never seen any if-statement written like that. And I haven’t found it in the SASS-documentation. Could you give me further sources for it?

Comment: I guess you can think of scoping that way.  PHP as a language doesn't have proper scoping like other languages do.  Sass has no *global* keyword, anything declared outside of curly braces is accessible inside.  The `if` function (not to be confused with `@if` control blocks) is here:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method

Comment: Eventually the auto-override in this answer will stop working! SASS now wants you to append ` !global` to the value when you're overriding a global var in block scope. Otherwise it will start making them local vars.

Comment: @cimmanon Why is PHP's scoping "improper" exactly? The problem is that this SASS scoping is weird: few would expect an `if` statement to create a new variable scope, and they're moving to make it even more like PHP's function scope: must declare global var use.

Comment: This behavior seems suprisingly different from most other languages and I don't see anything specific in the docs about variable scoping and @if blocks. Is it possible that this started off as a bug, and now became spec? Here are the docs: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: This was great info. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveClay (and speedplane): This answer is still correct. See [Variables: Flow Control Scope](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#flow-control-scope), where it says, 'Variables declared in flow control rules have special scoping rules: they don’t shadow variables at the same level as the flow control rule. Instead, they just assign to those variables. This makes it much easier to conditionally assign a value to a variable, or build up a value as part of a loop.'

Answer (score 9):

While this example is even *more* verbose, it eliminates the need to set two empty variables:

```scss
@if $colorscheme == white {
    $text-color: #333 !global;
    $background-color: #fff !global;
} @else {
    $text-color: #ccc !global;
    $background-color: #333 !global;
}
```

@cimmanon's 2nd and 3rd examples are much better, though.

Comment: The [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#flow-control-scope) say, 'Variables in flow control scope can assign to existing variables in the outer scope, but they can’t declare new variables there. Make sure the variable is already declared before you assign to it, even if you need to declare it as `null`.' Curiously, this does still work! But clearly, it's not the recommended way.