# Sass @if true statement not working function

Tags: function, if-statement, sass

I am trying to make a function which converts a pixel size to ems or rems. The function is as follows:

```
@function px2em($pixels, $fontSize: 16, $rem: false) {
    @if $rem == true {
        $unit: 0rem;
    } @else {
        $unit: 0em;
    }
    $ratio: 1 / $fontSize;
    @return ($pixels * $ratio) + $unit;
}
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
error style.scss (Line 36 of _functions.scss: Undefined variable: "$unit".)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SASS has `block scope`, variables defined in one block will only be available in that scope. So you want to use $unit outside of the if-else block, so you should declare it like this:

```
@function px2em($pixels, $fontSize: 16, $rem: false) {
    $unit: 0em;

    @if $rem == true {
        $unit: 0rem;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: So you cant declare a variable inside an @if statement?

Comment: @McShaman I updated my answer, take a look. You can indeed declare variables in if block, but that variable will only be available in that block. There is another SO question on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371332/sass-ignores-variables-defined-in-if-statement

Answer (score 7):

In this particular instance, you may want to use the `if()` function, rather than an `@if` statement

```
$unit: if($rem, 0rem, 0em);
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#if-instance_method