# Color themes with SASS mixins

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to create two color themes with SASS with help of the following mixin:

```
@mixin theme($name, $bgColor, $textColor) {
  .#{$name}{
    blockquote {
       @include borderLeft($textColor, $basicUnit/2);
    }
    strong {
        @include doubleFrame($bgColor, $textColor, 1px);
    }
    .highlighted {
        @include highlight($textColor);
    }
    .bb-custom-side.left .content-title {
        color: $textColor;
    }
    .content > h2 {
        border-top:$basicUnit/2 solid $bgColor;
    }
    .content { 
        background: $bgColor;
        color: $textColor;
    }
  }
}
```

And then just calling

```
@include theme("odd", $blue, $white);
@include theme("even", $green, $black);
```

inside **my _layout.scss**

But I keep getting this error and can't figure out what's wrong with my mixin:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...ily : "#{$name}": expected string, was "_#{$nameWeight}"";"
        on line 31 of /Users/Works/html/assets/scss/_typography.scss
        from line 11 of /Users/Works/html/assets/scss/main.scss
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

A newbie question...

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code that the error can be reproduced (there are undefined mixins and variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with one of the mixins you are using within your `theme` mixin (I suspect it is with `highlight` as that seems to be the only one dealing with font-family (mentioned in the trace of the error).

Removing the calls to those other mixins, this:

```
@mixin theme($name, $bgColor, $textColor) {
  .#{$name}{
    .content { 
        background: $bgColor;
        color: $textColor;
    }
  }
}

@include theme("odd", 'blue', 'white');
```

Produces this:

```
.odd .content {
  background: "blue";
  color: "white";
}
```

Which seems to be what you want.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Igpes)**

Comment: Thanks, there is another error that comes from font mixin: `@mixin font (
    $name:       apercu,
    $type:       static,
    $nameWeight: light,
    $size:       1.0em,
    $lineHeight: 1.4em, 
    $weight:     normal,
    $style:      normal, 
    $variant:    normal
    ) {
        @if $type != 'static' {
            $family: "#{$name}_#{$nameWeight}";
        }
        @else {
            $family : "#{$name}";
        }
        font: $style $variant $weight $size"/"$lineHeight $family, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif; }` which gives this error of undefined variable: "$family"

Comment: You need to define ``$family`` outside of your ``@if``/``@else`` blocks. Variables defined in control blocks like ``@if`` are not available in the rest of your mixin block. You can get around this by setting it to null like so ``$family: null`` before your @if statement. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15372344/1048479) for more explanation. Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nwzgJ)

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it has helped you : )