# Resuable spinner CSS3 animation. Has Sass changed?

Tags: css, sass

Can someone help me out and explain why this mixin that used to work now requires me to define vars before setting them inside a conditional. Did they add scope to Sass? Am I crazy?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with the Bundler/Compiler extension. I can't seem to find in the changelog for the compiler, or the Sass documentation, where or if this has been changed. All I know is it's been over a year since I touched this code and all of a sudden it doesn't work like this anymore.

If I add $from and $to definitions right after the initial @mixin line, it all works again. The original version of this mixin didn't include those, and it was working fine.

```
@mixin tspin($dir, $dur) {
    $from: 0deg;
    $to: 360deg;
    @if $dir == cw {
        $from: 0deg;
        $to: 360deg;
    }

    @if $dir == ccw {
       $from: 360deg;
       $to: 0deg;
    }
    @keyframes tspin-#{$dir} { from { transform: rotate($from); } to { transform: rotate($to); } }
    animation: tspin-#{$dir} #{$dur}s linear infinite;
}
```

Usage:

```
@include tspin("cw", "3");
```

Outputs:

```
animation: tspin-cw 3s linear infinite;
```

Comment: I don't think anything has changed recently. You'd see the same problem in this thread (from 2013) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371332/sass-ignores-variables-defined-in-if-statement If your variables within the if/else had a `!global` keyword then it would have worked but I don't see that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit -

To better answer your question. I come from a front end background & I was always taught not to declare vars in If statements within JS, as you get strange quirks. Now I doubt that SASS changed how their scope works, however you can check their change log [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html). But to me it would make sense that their scoping would follow some kind of JS best practise.

I think it's more likely that the Visual studios plugin had its own rule that wasn't as strict before an update, that allowed you to write vars in If blocks but has since changed to follow SASS best practise.

Your code looks right to me. I would tweak it just a little though, to make it easier to call and to not to repeat yourself you could have;

```
@mixin tspin($dur, $dir: cw) {
  $from: 0deg !default;
  $to: 360deg !default;

  @if $dir == ccw {
    $from: 360deg;
    $to: 0deg;
  }

  @keyframes tspin-#{$dir} { from { transform: rotate($from); } to { transform: rotate($to); } }
  animation: tspin-#{$dir} #{$dur}s linear infinite;
}
```

Then to call cw all you would need to do is;

```
@include tspin("3");
```

And ccw would be

```
@include tspin("3", "ccw");
```

You could even declare your from and to outside of the mixin if you wanted.

This talks about scss vars and scope in [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/understanding-variable-scope-in-sass--cms-23498)