# How to find class name in SCSS using if statement?

Tags: html, css, if-statement, sass, scss-mixins

I have two different classes. one is **admin** and one is **user**.

```
<div class="admin"> ... </div>
<div class="user"> ... </div>

$color : red !default;

@if('.admin'){
    $color : red;
} @else {
    $color : green;
}

input{
    border-color : $color;
    color : $color;
}

div{
    background : $color;
}
```

I want to do input border color dynamic. If parent class is admin than input border color is white and if parent class is user than input border color is black.

This is just an example, in my project two types of login and want to change so many things on using parent class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS ignores variables, defined in if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371332/sass-ignores-variables-defined-in-if-statement)

Comment: In that if statement use variables. And in my case find class name in if statement. so both are different things.

Comment: I would guess you are approaching your problem the wrong way, I refer to my answer.

Comment: Is it possible to apply css using find class name in if statement?

Comment: No, not in the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can nest those classes like this. The "&" means if the parent class is this (admin or user), let input have this `border-color`. For me I, lets say I'll do my css for `admin` and then `input`, if there is any conditions like if a parent is gone modify the appearance of the `input`, I nest those inside to have it all in one place for that particular id, class or direct tag.

```
.admin { 
  background : red; 
}

.user { 
  background : green; 
}

input {
  border-color: deepskyblue;

  .admin & {
    border-color: white;
  }

  .user & {
    border-color: black;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using if statement only because my code is so long. I have applied many css for color, border-color and box-shadow.

`input{ border-color: red; color: red}
textarea{border-color: red}`

Comment: In sass you dont really use `if` unless it's for functions. You might be approaching it wrong if you feel you need `if` in your sass. Can you post a real example of some class with "lots of css"?

Comment: `$color : red !default;

@if('.admin'){
 $color : red;
} @else {
 $color : green;
}

input{
 border-color : $color;
 color : $color;
}

div{
 background : $color;
}`

Comment: @smartsense-designer Ok you can do that like theme based, not sure how you are gone solve changing the "theme variable" based on state? From what I understand you have no option but to use my solution, or the Sandeep one. It comes down to preference.

Comment: Yes. those both is right solution but, I have already scss code for 4000 lines. I have two types of login. and on using parent class my scss apply in whole files. so this solution not work for me.

Comment: @smartsense-designer but what is your solution today? Like is this a new addition to your requirements to have two types of "themes" `user` and `admin`? There is no way around it as I know at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
.admin{ 
    background : red; 
    input{
        border-color:#fff;
    }
}
.user{ 
    background : red; 
    input{
        border-color:#000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to find class name using if statement so I can apply color name dynamically in my whole file. If user has login than apply X color and admin has login than apply Y color.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.